# Despite the auto margin on both sides, the content still moves around horizontally on subpages

Tags: html, css

In the CSS, I have set a maximum width for the body, a display: flex and auto margins on both sides. Despite this, in most cases when I click on a post, the content is still slightly moving horizontally. This only happens on desktop view, I don't know why.

[Here](https://wonderful-lovelace-4c83e3.netlify.app/) is an example when clicking on the "Test 2" (or almost any other) post moves the body horizontally. However, clicking on the "Test" no longer moves the body.

The body looks like this in the CSS:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: $bg-color;
  color: $font-color;
  font: 20px/1.5 $fonts;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 650px;
}
```

Comment: why not use `body { justify-content: center; }`?

Comment: It is your browser adding the vertical scroll bar which causes your content to slightly move.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe how trivial the solution was. I completely forgot the scrollbar.
`html { overflow-y: scroll; }`
However, as far as I know, there is no way to accept comments as answers.